# How do i fix the function displayBal?

Tags: c++, io, project

Okay so everytime i run the code and creates an infinite loop, but within that infinite loop the balance is displaying this huge number:

Balance = $-92559631349317830736831783200707727132248687965119994463780864.00
when i need it to display 
Balance = 2000

```
// Author:      
// Source file: 
// Description: 
// Compiler used:   

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct records
{
    int code;
    double amount;
};
// Function Prototypes
void displayTitle();
double getBegBal(ifstream&);
void displayBal(records);
records getData(ifstream&);
double processCheck(double, double);
double processDeposit(double, double);
double processATM(double, double);
double processSvcChg(double);


//Global Constants
const double    CHARGE = 10,
ATMFEE = 2;

int main()
{
    //Variable Declarations
    int transCode;
    double balance,
        transAmt;


    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);

    records trans;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("c:\\checkIn.dat");

    displayTitle();
    balance = getBegBal(inFile);
    getData(inFile);

    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        trans = getData(inFile);

        switch (trans.code)
        {
        case 1: balance = processCheck(balance, trans.amount); break;
        case 2: balance = processDeposit(balance, trans.amount); break;
        case 3: balance = processATM(balance, trans.amount); break;
        }
        displayBal(trans);
        if (balance < 0)
            balance = processSvcChg(balance);
        getData(inFile);
    }

    return 0;
}


void displayTitle()
{
    cout << "\n       Check Register\n\n";
}

double getBegBal(ifstream& inFile)
{
    //double bal;
    records balance;
    inFile >> balance.amount;
    displayBal(balance);
    return balance.amount;
}

void displayBal(records rec)
{
    cout << "\t\tBalance = $" << setw(10) << rec.amount;
}

records getData(ifstream& inFile)
{
    records rec;
    inFile >> rec.code >> rec.amount;
    return rec;
}

double processCheck(double bal, double amt)
{
    records trans;
    trans.amount = 0;
    cout << "\n  Check =    " << setw(10) << trans.amount;
    return (bal - amt);
}

double processDeposit(double bal, double amt)
{
    records trans;
    trans.amount = 0;
    cout << "\n  Deposit =  " << setw(10) << trans.amount;
    return (bal + amt);
}
double processATM(double bal, double amt)
{
    records trans;
    trans.amount = 0;
    cout << "\n  ATM     =  " << setw(10) << trans.amount;
    bal = bal - amt;
    displayBal(trans);
    bal = bal - ATMFEE;
    cout << "\n  ATM Fee =  " << setw(10) << ATMFEE;
    return (bal);
}
double processSvcChg(double bal)
{
    records trans;
    trans.amount = 0;
    cout << "\n  Service chg =" << setw(8) << CHARGE;
    bal = bal - CHARGE;
    displayBal(trans);
    return (bal);
}
```

also here is the data file it is suppose to read from

```
2000 1 1225.72 1 463.81 3 200 1 632 2 1500 1 300 2 1800
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking for errors. Try `while (inFile)` instead of `while (!inFile.eof())`. You might want to consider dropping some `assert(inFile)` after every read to make sure it actually worked.